# QDir entryList function strange behavior

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qdir

I'm using VS2019, Qt 5.15.2

I'm using `entryList` method of the class `QDir` on the following directory:

[image]

The following behavior of the `entryList` method with the `QDir::NoDotAndDotDot` parameter  is strange:

tTe following example is self explanatory:
My code :

```cpp
    LOG( INFO ) << "entryList with no parameter";
    foreach( auto elementName, p_dir.entryList() )
    {
        LOG( INFO ) << "elementName : " << elementName.toStdString();
    }

    LOG( INFO ) << "entryList with QDir::NoDotAndDotDot";
    foreach( auto elementName, p_dir.entryList( QDir::NoDotAndDotDot ) )
    {
        LOG( INFO ) << "elementName : " << elementName.toStdString();
    }
```

The output is as follows:

```
2021-04-01-10:29:33,482724 | INFO            | entryList with no parameter | xxxxxxxxx.cpp->RecursiveProcessingFilesFinder:58
2021-04-01-10:29:33,482773 | INFO            | elementName : . | xxxxxxxxx.cpp->RecursiveProcessingFilesFinder:61
2021-04-01-10:29:33,482805 | INFO            | elementName : .. | xxxxxxxxx.cpp->RecursiveProcessingFilesFinder:61
2021-04-01-10:29:33,482844 | INFO            | elementName : ABDOMEN | xxxxxxxxx.cpp->RecursiveProcessingFilesFinder:61
2021-04-01-10:29:33,482876 | INFO            | elementName : CHEST | xxxxxxxxx.cpp->RecursiveProcessingFilesFinder:61
2021-04-01-10:29:33,482913 | INFO            | elementName : CSPINE | xxxxxxxxx.cpp->RecursiveProcessingFilesFinder:61
2021-04-01-10:29:33,482944 | INFO            | elementName : ELBOW | xxxxxxxxx.cpp->RecursiveProcessingFilesFinder:61
2021-04-01-10:29:33,482985 | INFO            | elementName : FOOT | xxxxxxxxx.cpp->RecursiveProcessingFilesFinder:61
2021-04-01-10:29:33,483019 | INFO            | elementName : HAND | xxxxxxxxx.cpp->RecursiveProcessingFilesFinder:61
2021-04-01-10:29:33,483053 | INFO            | elementName : KNEE | xxxxxxxxx.cpp->RecursiveProcessingFilesFinder:61
2021-04-01-10:29:33,483090 | INFO            | elementName : LSPINE | xxxxxxxxx.cpp->RecursiveProcessingFilesFinder:61
2021-04-01-10:29:33,483123 | INFO            | elementName : PELVIS | xxxxxxxxx.cpp->RecursiveProcessingFilesFinder:61
2021-04-01-10:29:33,483155 | INFO            | elementName : RIB | xxxxxxxxx.cpp->RecursiveProcessingFilesFinder:61
2021-04-01-10:29:33,483186 | INFO            | elementName : SHOULDER | xxxxxxxxx.cpp->RecursiveProcessingFilesFinder:61
2021-04-01-10:29:33,483221 | INFO            | elementName : SKULL | xxxxxxxxx.cpp->RecursiveProcessingFilesFinder:61
2021-04-01-10:29:33,483252 | INFO            | elementName : TSPINE | xxxxxxxxx.cpp->RecursiveProcessingFilesFinder:61
2021-04-01-10:29:33,483284 | INFO            | entryList with QDir::NoDotAndDotDot | xxxxxxxxx.cpp->RecursiveProcessingFilesFinder:64
```

I don't catch why, if I use the filter `QDir::NoDotAndDotDot`, entryList output is now empty ???

Comment: Shouldn't you use it in combination with the other filter like: `p_dir.entryList( QDir::NoDotAndDotDot | QDir::Dirs )`?

Comment: TY. I want to retrieve any kind of entry: dirs and files. which is the normal behavior when no filter is set. Really strange

Comment: Then use `p_dir.entryList( QDir::NoDotAndDotDot | QDir::Dirs | QDir::Files )`

Answer (score 2):

Your question is :

> I don't catch why, if I use the filter `QDir::NoDotAndDotDot`

The official documentation of `QDir::entryList` states [that](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdir.html#entryList)

> it returns an empty list if the directory is unreadable, does not exist, or **if nothing matches the specification.**

When you are doing `p_dir.entryList()`, the defaulft filter is `NoFilter` so it is normal to display all things.
The normal behavior is `NoFilter` which means displaying all things including `.` (Dot) and `..` (DotDot)

When you are doing `p_dir.entryList( QDir::NoDotAndDotDot )`, the filter is set to `QDir::NoDotAndDotDot` which means `"Do not list the special entries "." and ".."."` (see [description of QDir::Filters](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdir.html#Filter-enum) and then nothing more matches the specification of the filter thus, it outputs an empty list.

To display all things without the line `entryList with QDir::NoDotAndDotDot...`, you should do:

```cpp
foreach( auto elementName, p_dir.entryList( QDir::AllDirs | QDir::Files |QDir::NoDotAndDotDot )
{
    LOG( INFO ) << "elementName : " << elementName.toStdString();
}
```

This allows for displaying:

- `QDir::AllDirs` - List all directories; i.e. don't apply the filters to directory names.
- `QDir::Files` - List files.
- `QDir::NoDotAndDotDot`- Do not list the special entries "." and "..".

Comment: TY. 
I understand but I find it confusing and misleading. Using filter option "NoDotNoDotDot" alone is equivalent to list nothing ... It is not intuitive to me.
'if nothing matches the specification' in this case, is not clear to me: the specification is "NoDotNoDotDot", which means "do not list the special entries "." and ".."" but the default behavior (said in Qt documentation) is "NoFilter", that is to say "list all". I would expect that all the entries, except the special ones "." and "..", would be listed when I'm using only the "NoDotNoDotDot" filter option alone.
TY again

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. Happy to contribute.